# A proposal for Open Data SE

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, area51

I would like to announce that on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) there is a proposal new Stack Exchange site - [Open Data](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data?referrer=xxEIi7iMeJfat7cFwtHzOQ2).

> **Open Data**
>
> Proposed Q&A site for developers and researchers interested in open data.

Currently it is in commitment phase - so i.e. gathering a critical mass of participants. If you are interested, [go there and click "commit"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data?referrer=xxEIi7iMeJfat7cFwtHzOQ2).

(I am posting it here, as Open Data is a topic which has a big intersection with academic issues, especially related to Open Science.)